# split a string with multiple alphabets and letters - android

Tags: java, android

Very new to android java and I have a simple question. I have **string** for example like this :

```
P:38,AS:31,DT:231,AR:21
```

I want to split this into 4 different lists in the form :

```
P(list)  = 38
AS(list) = 31
DT(list) = 231
AR(list) = 21
```

I tried split but it didnt get the job done ...

Comment: Why didn't split get the job done?

Comment: I got confused on the output it gave me, and got lost ... also it doesnt accept P or P: as the regex idk why :/

Comment: @PoByBolek I am very new to java and just trying out simple excercises

Comment: Okay... did you try splitting by comma and then processing each entry individually?

Comment: @PoByBolek that could be a problem if there are multiple entries ... for example if its P:38,98,AS:34,22 then it would just remove the commas and

Comment: @PoByBolek and crumble up the data

Comment: That wasn't very clear from the example you provided.... Are the list keys (P, AS, DT, AR) constant or can there be more than four lists?

Comment: @PoByBolek i realized that i forgot to mention but P, AS, DT, AR are infact keys for the values ahead of them until eventually they do not find another key or reach the end of the string

Comment: But will it always be those four keys or are there other strings where the keys may be DF, HK, UT, MHL, PO, and Q, for example?

Comment: @PoByBolek just these for now ... cant predict the future :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as the keys are always letters and the values are always integers, you can use regular expressions to parse these strings:

```
Hashtable<String, int[]> result = new Hashtable<String, int[]>();
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([A-Z]+):(\\d+(?:,\\d+)*)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);

while (matcher.find()) {
    String key = matcher.group(1);
    String[] fields = matcher.group(2).split(",");

    int[] values = new int[fields.length];
    for (int i=0; i<values.length; i++)
        values[i] = Integer.parseInt(fields[i]);

    result.put(key, values);
}
```

#### Edit

`"([A-Z]+):(\\d+(?:,\\d+)*)"` is a [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_basic_and_extended) that matches at least one uppercase letter (`[A-Z]+`) followed by a colon (`:`) followed by one more numbers separated by commas (`\\d+(?:,\\d+)*`). A single number is composed of one more digits (`\\d+`). The additional parentheses allow us to later access the individual parts of the input string using the `group(int)` method calls.

The [`java.util.regex.Matcher`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) class allows us to iterate through the individual parts of the input string that match our regular expression. The [`find()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find--) method returns `true` as long as there is another substring in our input string that matches the regular expression. So with the input string `"P:38,45,AS:31,DT:231,345,678,AR:21"` the `while` loop would execute four times and the `matcher` variable would point to the following four substrings of the input string:

- `P:38,45`
- `AS:31`
- `DT:231,345,678`
- `AR:21`

We can then use the `matcher`'s [`group(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group-int-) method to access the individual parts of each substring. `matcher.group(1)` accesses the text that was captured by the first parentheses of our regular expression (`([A-Z]+)`) which corresponds to `"P"`, `"AS"`, `"DT"`, and `"AR"` in the individual loop iterations. Analogously, `matcher.group(2)` corresponds to the second parentheses of the regular expression (`(\\d+(?:,\\d+)*)`) which would return `"38,45"`, `"31"`, `"231,345,678"`, and `"21"`. So in the first iteration of the `while` loop `key` would hold `"P"` and `fields` would hold an array of strings `["38", "45"]`. We can then parse the fields into actual integer values using [`Integer.parseInt(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt-java.lang.String-) and store the key and the values in a [`Hashtable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html) so that we can later retrieve the values for the individual keys. For example, `result.get("DT")` would return an array of integers with the values `[231, 345, 678]`.

Comment: @SaimMahmood If that answered your question, could you please accept it?

Comment: i tried you code but it gives me answer like this ... 
the answer for results is 
       {AS=[I@222f6e2f, DT=[I@291e6c3c, AR=[I@39568dc5, P=  [I@346a931a}


any idea what this is? and also when i try to access them using the key and tag the results in log i dont get anything ....

Comment: What you are seeing are the string representations of the integer arrays. If you want to see the actual values, you must print them separately and not like `System.out.println(result.get("DT"))`

Comment: doing this for android and this is what i wrote ... 


            Log.i("inside homfragment ", " results values for AR in result \n" + result.get("AR").toString());


still nothing

Comment: Again, what you are seeing is the string representation of the integer array, which unfortunately doesn't show you its values. You'd have to do something like: `int[] values = result.get("DT"); for (int i=0; i<values.length; i++) Log.i("values[" + i + "] for DT: " + values[i]);`

Comment: IT WORKS!!! would have given you a 100000 upvotes if possible, thanks mate god bless you :D

Comment: hello, any idea how to make this method stop in between of an iteration? I have some more values and want to stop before it...

Answer (score 0):

As @pobybolek said, you can use his method which he wrote to take the string and convert it into a hashtable, which uses the key and then the int values after it. The int values are stored in an array and the key is a string.

```
                        String input = master_string;
                        Hashtable<String, int[]> result = new Hashtable<String, int[]>();
                        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([A-Z]+):(\\d+(?:,\\d+)*)");
                        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);

                        while (matcher.find())
                        {
                            String key = matcher.group(1);
                            String[] fields = matcher.group(2).split(",");

                            int[] values = new int[fields.length];
                            for (int pqr=0; pqr<values.length; pqr++)
                            {
                                values[pqr] = Integer.parseInt(fields[pqr]);
                                // values[pqr] = fields[pqr];
                            }
                            result.put(key, values);
                        }
```

the above code splits the given string into its keys and the values after the key into an integer array, this can also be changed into a String key, String[] array as seen in the second line of my code.